# Ionic Error when adding new platform

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.13
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
OS: Distributor ID:     Ubuntu Description:     Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Node Version: v0.10.41
```

When I attempt to run the following command:

```
ionic platform add android
```

It returns the following error:

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Running command: /home/vagrant/projects/financeApp/hooks/before_platform_add/init_directories.js /home/vagrant/projects/financeApp
Error: Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: ETXTBSY, rename '/home/vagrant/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.1.1/package.tgz.169934643'
```

I've attempted to remove the `.cordova` folder and I've installed the Android SDK, the android command in the console works, and I've added an android device, but cordova nor ionic are working whenever I try to add a platform. I get this same error for any platform.

Comment: I think you need to give permission to project folder to add dynamic directory

Comment: maybe poor connection

Comment: @SantoshShinde I tried `sudo chown -R vagrant .` , and still same issue, I also updated Node and npm

Comment: please try this chmod 777 -R /your/Project/directory

Comment: @SantoshShinde Still same error.

Comment: Please try chmod -R 755 hooks/

Comment: @SantoshShinde Unfortunately, same error.

Comment: Please refer this https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/01/hooks-apache-cordova-mobile-applications/

Comment: @SantoshShinde I fixed it :)

Comment: try sudo ionic platform add android command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue regarding Hooks With Apache Cordova Mobile Applications and permission for more help refer this [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/hooks-apache-cordova-mobile-applications/)

`chmod 777 hooks/before_prepare/01_junkcleanup.js`

Hopes this will help you !

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the same thing for other platforms

Comment: @NISHANKKUMAR https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/hooks-apache-cordova-mobile-applications/